# With NUnit, what project type in Visual Studio do I need to use to create my test project?

Tags: visual-studio, nunit

When I am creating a test project in Visual Studio, do I just create a C# console project type, then import Nunit?

Does the GUI then hook into this project somehow?

There seems to be tons of nunit related .dll's, which ones do I need?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just create a class library (i.e. a DLL).  You only need to import nunit.framework.dll.

Yes, the nUnit GUI loads your assembly (which can be a DLL or a .EXE) and finds all the **public** classes which have been marked with the appropriate attributes.

Comment: @Will Dean: Thanks for answers. However, as I'm new in all of this, can you be a little more explicit? Create a class library how? for what? At the same time, I need to import NUnit.Framework from where? (I guess my TestProject).

Comment: You said to create a class library, but this is not an option according to the NUnit documentation. "Why can't my tests target .NET Standard Visual Studio and VSTest require that the tests target a specific platform. .NET Standard is like a Portable library in that it does not target any specific platform, but can run on any supported platform" https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/getting-started/dotnet-core-and-dotnet-standard.html#why-cant-my-tests-target-net-standard

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend checking out the TestDriven.Net Visual Studio plugin.  It allows you to run your tests right from VS, so there's no need to fire up the NUnit GUI.

http://www.testdriven.net/

Comment: or Resharper that also supports this

Comment: You should have mentioned it comes with `Buy Now` feature :/